# How do I use basic linux commands to delete all files except one?

Tags: command-line, delete

I want to delete all the files within a directory that start with `abc` except for `abc` itself.

example:

```
abc abc1 abc2
```

How would I delete `abc1` and `abc2` only in a single command line?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the shell glob `abc?*` to match `abc` followed by at least one character

```
rm abc?*
```

e.g.

```
$ ls abc*
abc  abc1  abc2
$ ls abc?*
abc1  abc2
```

so

```
$ rm abc?*
$ ls abc*
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative shell way:

```
$ for f in abc*; do case "$f" in "abc") continue;; *) echo "$f";; esac;done
```

replace `echo` with `rm` after testing.